# Doing SparseMat (sparse matrix) operations in openCV

Tags: opencv, sparse-matrix

I need to do matrix operations (mainly multiply and inverse) of a sparse matrix SparseMat in OpenCV.
I noticed that you can only iterate and insert values to SparseMat.
Is there an external code I can use? (or am I missing something?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just that sparse matrices are not really suited for inversion or matrix-matrix-multiplication, so it's quite reasonable there is no builtin function for that. They're actually more used for matrix-vector multiplication (usually when solving iterative linear systems).

What you can do is solve N linear systems (with the columns of the identity matrix as right hand sides) to get the inverse matrix. But then you need N*N storage for the inverse matrix anyway, so using a dense matrix with a usual decompositions algorithm would be a better way to do it, as the performance gain won't be that high when doing N iterative solutions. Or maybe some sparse direct solvers like [SuperLU](http://crd.lbl.gov/~xiaoye/SuperLU/) or [TAUCS](http://www.tau.ac.il/~stoledo/taucs/) may help, but I doubt that OpenCV has such functionalities.

You should also think if you really need the inverse matrix. Often such problem are also solvable by just solving a linear system, which can be done with a sparse matrix quite easily and fast via e.g. CG or BiCGStab.

Comment: I do need the inverse matrix itself because it will be used as a filter to a signal later on in the algorithm. I had reasons to beleive that the inverse matrix is rather sparse too so that an inverse algorithm of a sparse matrix will be more efficient than non sparse one, but you do have a point...

Comment: @Boaz In general the inverse of a sparse matrix need not be sparse, I think.

Answer (score -3):

You can convert a SparseMat to a Mat, do what operations you need and then convert back.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Could you please expand on your post, so that the logic behind what you mentioned can be understood? For more information, there's some useful information on [answer]. Thank you!

Comment: Usually, the reason `SparseMat` ones are used is because the original `Mat` won't fit in the computer's memory. Converting to Mat isn't an option.

Answer (score -5):

you can use **Eigen** library directly. **Eigen** works together with **OpenCV** very well.

Comment: If you have something more to add to your own answer, you can click the edit button to add that, instead of adding another answer. You can always edit your own posts, and you can also suggest edits to other people's posts if they need improving.

Comment: And you can delete your answer if you don't like this one. And merge whatever you want to say in your first answer.